# Bootstrap(3.0.0) Preventing Modal to Pre-load content

Tags: google-maps-api-3, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following codes:

```
<div id="makatiPD" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Makati City Office</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="540" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=King's+Court+Building.,+Makati+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=kings+court&amp;sll=13.656663,124.090576&amp;sspn=9.2249,9.876709&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=King's+Court+Bldg+2,+Dela+Rosa+Street,+Lungsod+ng+Makati,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;t=m&amp;ll=14.558164,121.013203&amp;spn=0.029076,0.046349&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=King's+Court+Building.,+Makati+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=kings+court&amp;sll=13.656663,124.090576&amp;sspn=9.2249,9.876709&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=King's+Court+Bldg+2,+Dela+Rosa+Street,+Lungsod+ng+Makati,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;t=m&amp;ll=14.558164,121.013203&amp;spn=0.029076,0.046349&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<div id="quezonPD" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Quezon City Office</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="540" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Phil-Data+Building,+265+E.+Rodriguez+Sr.+Avenue,+Quezon+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;aq=&amp;sll=14.618293,121.006191&amp;sspn=0.00898,0.009645&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Phil-Data+Building,&amp;hnear=E+Rodriguez+Sr.+Ave,+Quezon+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;ll=14.618293,121.006191&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Phil-Data+Building,+265+E.+Rodriguez+Sr.+Avenue,+Quezon+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;aq=&amp;sll=14.618293,121.006191&amp;sspn=0.00898,0.009645&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Phil-Data+Building,&amp;hnear=E+Rodriguez+Sr.+Ave,+Quezon+City,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&amp;ll=14.618293,121.006191&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

It's working perfectly fine and have no problem with regards to calling it. However, doesn't this kind of set up somehow hinder my site's loading time? I haven't really experienced any trouble but since I'm still running the website locally, I'm not quite sure if this might generate a few problems when I do deploy it.

More info: 
The page loads just fine locally, but it continues to show that it's loading something. (I think it's the 2 iFrames.)

So is there some way to somehow only load the iframes when I fire each individual modals?

Comment: twitter Modal is designed to be a just another div which will be hidden initially, but show up on some action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter-Bootstrap Modal is designed to be a just another div which will be hidden initially, but show up on some action...

Yes, you can dynamically load that div. [Here](https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/1688900) is an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `iframe` component is used in Bootstrap Modal. It's using `div`. Yes it is possible, if you want to load it dynamically you can load using `ajax` and `javascript`.
Inside `.modal-body` you have used `iframe`, for loading each modal differently try to load with `ajax` and with `javascript` after successfully the request is made and after receiving the result with `javascript` you can show the loaded modal like-

```
$('#ModalId').modal();
```

Comment: I'm using an iframe inside my modal. Check inside "modal-body".

Comment: I used codeMan's answer since it was easier to set up. I know your answer would've also worked, thank you very much!